# Adding a number to a passwords from a rainbow table

Tags: security, passwords

For my Security class I was given this assignment:

```
Break into "wpa2own" (WPA2-PSK protected) on campus.

Your source can't recall the exact passphrase, but it's SSID was "wpa2own" 
and she remembered that the password started with a number 
(coincidentally your student ID [studentID]) concatenated with a password 
out of a famous, real-world password list from the Internet: [studentID][password]).
```

I'm already set in terms of running the necessary software, but how do I get my Linux box to append [studentID] to my already existing word list? I already looked at "Crunch", a password-list creation software, but that doesn't have this functionality.

Comment: Perhaps write a small script? `bash`, `perl`, `python`…even *shudder* `ruby` can all do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to write a script, use sed:

```
sed 's/^/studentID/' passwordlist.txt > out.txt
```

This will add your 'studentID' to the beginning of each line

Comment: Thanks! The kind of solution I was looking for.